# Laravel 5.3 POST and tokenmismatch

Tags: php, laravel-5, http-post, token

I have a page that I want to have a POST sent to which will trigger a database update. The request will come from another site.

```
Route::post('update', 'DatabaseController@update');
```

The request includes a single element

(raw)

```
id=12345
```

(form-data)

```
id: 12345
```

Whenever I access the page, I get this error

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel makes it easy to protect your application from cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attacks. Cross-site request forgeries are a type of malicious exploit whereby unauthorized commands are performed on behalf of an authenticated user.

Laravel automatically generates a CSRF "token" for each active user session managed by the application. This token is used to verify that the authenticated user is the one actually making the requests to the application.

Anytime you define a HTML form in your application, you should include a hidden CSRF token field in the form so that the CSRF protection middleware can validate the request. You may use the csrf_field helper to generate the token field:

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    ...
</form>
```

In addition to checking for the CSRF token as a POST parameter, the VerifyCsrfToken middleware will also check for the X-CSRF-TOKEN request header. You could, for example, store the token in a HTML meta tag:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then, once you have created the meta tag, you can instruct a library like jQuery to automatically add the token to all request headers. This provides simple, convenient CSRF protection for your AJAX based applications:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf)

**Note:** To exclude some URI's from CSRF verification go to `project/app/Http/Middleware`, open the file `VerifyCsrfToken.php` and pass your url like:

```
protected $except = [
    '/api/authuser',
];
```

the url passed in this array are excluded from URI's from CSRF verification.

Comment: I don't really have any control over what the "sender" sends. All I know for sure is that there is an element called "id" with a 5 digit id.

Comment: In your reference, I did find a section that describes how to exclude URIs from csrf! So, that solved my problem! Thanks.

Comment: You can up-vote to if you think this answer helps you :P