# How to post from other system to laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've someone connecting to my system. Form one system when user submits the form, I have to get the value of uesrname in my system.

```
<form action="user/update" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="Username" id="Username" value="fazeela.ma@rapidvaluesolutions.com" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Which is using a route in may laravel system.

Route::post('user/update', 'Login\LoginController@test');

But this giving me a token mismatch error.

How do I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.3 POST and tokenmismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43244200/laravel-5-3-post-and-tokenmismatch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a CSRF issure and can be resolved by reading this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf.